# Have I upgraded a package, and why is there a mismatch of its version shown?

Tags: apt, package-management, xpra

Originally

```
$ xpra --version
xpra v3.0.7-r25627
```

I then upgraded xpra by

```
$ sudo apt install xpra
[sudo] password for t: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  xpra
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 314 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://xpra.org bionic/main amd64 xpra amd64 3.0.8-r25889-1 [314 kB]
Fetched 314 kB in 1s (267 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 485411 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xpra_3.0.8-r25889-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xpra (3.0.8-r25889-1) over (3.0.7-r25627-1) ...
Setting up xpra (3.0.8-r25889-1) ...
```

But then

```
$ xpra --version
xpra v3.0.7-r25627
```

and

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i xpra
ii  python2-xpra                                  3.0.7-r25627-1                                   amd64        tool to detach/reattach running X programs
ii  python3-xpra                                  3.0.7-r25627-1                                   amd64        tool to detach/reattach running X programs
ii  xpra                                          3.0.8-r25889-1                                   amd64        tool to detach/reattach running X programs
ii  xpra-html5                                    3.0.7-r25627-1                                   amd64        html5 xpra client
```

and

```
$ sudo apt install xpra
[sudo] password for t: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xpra is already the newest version (3.0.8-r25889-1).
```

Why is the mismatch of xpra version shown?

Is it due to package xpra or to apt or dpkg?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no any version mismatch. xpra is a python library (with a little frontend), and your library version is 3.0.7-r25627-1.

Comment: Can you be clearer?

Comment: ii  python2-xpra                                  **3.0.7-r25627-1**                                   amd64        tool to detach/reattach running X programs

ii  python3-xpra                                  **3.0.7-r25627-1**                                   amd64        tool to detach/reattach running X programs

Answer (score 2):

You have upgraded a package, but you haven’t upgraded the package which determines which version of Xpra you’re really using.

As Ipor says, [the upstream Xpra packages](http://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Download#Linux) split their contents between a small `xpra` package containing the launcher scripts (and configuration, etc.), and Python packages containing the implementation.

To upgrade Xpra you need to upgrade all the Xpra-related packages:

```
sudo apt install xpra xpra-html5 python3-xpra
```

The `xpra` package *could* declare a strictly-versioned dependency on the other Xpra packages, which would cause them all to be upgraded with `sudo apt install xpra`; but it doesn’t, which is why it’s up to the user to make sure they’re all kept in sync. (I imagine the upstream packagers assume users upgrade all their packages all the time.)

You can delete the Python 2 package, it’s no longer needed:

```
sudo apt purge python2-xpra
```

Comment: I'm not a Linux user, but it seems a bit weird that you can upgrade `xpra` without upgrading the libraries it depends(?) on.

Comment: Yes, it is somewhat unfortunate (and would be easy to fix by the packagers). This is only a problem with the Xpra-provided packages; the Debian and Ubuntu packages don’t have this deficiency.

Comment: Thanks. (1) A generic question: how do you figure out what actual packages to upgrade for a nominal package, such as "to upgrade Xpra you need to upgrade all the Xpra-related packages: ..."? (2) Was I wrong when I thought I solved the problem here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578617/674?

Comment: (3) Does `apt install`  install dependencies for a package not yet installed, but not upgrade dependencies for an installed package? When upgrading an installed package,  does not upgrading its dependencies happen all the time, or only if the upgraded package can work without upgrading its dependenices? (so in my case, is it because a version of xpra can work with various versions of xpra-html5 and python3-xpra, and they are completely independent packages?)

Comment: (1) Generally speaking I don’t, I keep my entire installation up-to-date. When I need to upgrade small parts, I look at the details of the package construction and dependencies. (2) Probably, at least regarding the source of the fix. (3) `apt` is a solver. When you say `apt install xpra`, it looks at the constraints that are added, and possibly broken, and fixes them. If any of `xpra`’s dependencies are missing, that will mean installing them. If any of `xpra`’s dependencies are too old, that will mean upgrading them. Anything else won’t cause an automatic change.

Comment: “Too old” is determined by the declared dependencies and their versions: since `xpra` doesn’t specify versions for its Python Xpra dependencies, they will never be considered too old.

Comment: I was wondering where  xpra declares its dependencies (and missing versions of dependencies)?

Comment: `apt show xpra`